# How can I join one table with another and count the number of registers of an item per day?

Tags: sql, database, join, databricks

I'm stuck with a problem here. I have 2 tables: one with produts and the day they were checked by an employee at the warehouse (date_checked) and another one with sales data, as you can see bellow:

```
PRODUCTS
    date_checked |  product_name       | category       | product_id
_____________________________________________________________________
0   2021-01-01   |  tv                 | entertainment  | 100
1   2021-01-03   |  laptop             | business       | 110
```

```
SALES
    sale_date    |  product_name       | category       | product_id
_____________________________________________________________________
0   2021-01-01   |  tv                 | entertainment  | 100
1   2021-01-01   |  laptop             | business       | 110
2   2021-01-01   |  tv                 | entertainment  | 100
3   2021-01-01   |  laptop             | business       | 110
4   2021-01-01   |  tv                 | entertainment  | 100
5   2021-01-03   |  laptop             | business       | 110
6   2021-01-03   |  tv                 | entertainment  | 100
7   2021-01-03   |  laptop             | business       | 110
7   2021-01-03   |  laptop             | business       | 110
```

My goal here is to create a new table with all the data of the PRODUCTS table plus the number of produts sold in the date_checked. For example: the tv product was checked january 1st, and on that same day 3 tvs were sold. The laptop was checked january 3rd and 3 laptops were sold that day, as you can see here:

```
SALES_AT_CHECK_DAY
    date_checked |  product_name       | category       | product_id | sales
_____________________________________________________________________________
0   2021-01-01   |  tv                 | entertainment  | 100        | 3
1   2021-01-03   |  laptop             | business       | 110        | 3
```

I know i need to use a join here, but I just can't manage to count how many products were sold on a given day. Could you guys please helpe me?

Thank you very much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you seem to have a poor data model, because you are repeating columns between the two tables.  You should only have the primary key in `sales` and then be looking up the other information.

```
select p.date_checked, s.product_name, s.category, s.product_id, 
       count(*) as sales
from sales s join
     products p
     on s.product_id = p.product_id and
        s.sale_date = p.date_checked
group by p.date_checked, s.product_name, s.category, s.product_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

- First Join the data
- Count(*) will count rows based on the aggregation provided. In our case it is the entire product columns i.e products.*
- Specify those columns in group by

```
select 
   products.*,
   count(*) as sales
from sales 
inner join products 
on sales.product_id = products.product_id 
and sales.sale_date = products.date_checked
group by 
        products.date_checked,
        products.product_name, 
        products.category, 
        products.product_id
```